# What does "Strawman Scenario" mean?

Tags: expressions

I've come across the following statement while reading an article.

> In the **strawman scenario** shown in Figure 4(a), we use Iperf to
>   measure the bandwidth between STA3 and H4 during 60s.

Figure 4(a) depicts a diagram utilized as an example to help to explain the text.
However, what does *strawman scenario* actually mean?

Comment: Thanks for your first question.  Context of the article might help to understand the use of the term for this case.  Can you link to the article or provide more context?  What research have you done?

Comment: Thanks for your advice, next time I'll try to create a more elaborated question. The field here is 'networking'. The sentence cited in the question can be found on: Pg.6 Section 5.1, Second paragraph https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01480973/document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strawman usually refers to a weak form of an argument that's easier to refute than the original. In this case, though, the text is probably using it in the sense that this is a very simplified example intended only to demonstrate the concept. It should not be taken as representative of a problem you might actually encounter in real life.

Comment: Thanks! I think that this is the meaning intended by the author.

Answer (score 1):

In traditional forms of English dating from the 19th century, *man of straw* was a figurative expression meaning a businessman who had no financial substance behind him, in other words someone who's appearance - as a merchant or businessman - seemed on the face of it to be sound, but who in reality was impecunious.

He would seem to all outward appearances to be financially robust -- as solid as the Bank of England. But if put to the test, he actually had all the substance and solidity of a scarecrow -- a man literally made of straw. We might today describe him as having all the solidity of a soap bubble.

The expression seems to have been in vogue in the 1830s, at the time of the *South Sea Bubble*, the greatest financial scandle of the 19th Century, when the South Sea company collapsed, with huge debts, to the financial ruin of many of its investors.